# Как привести слова вида Pröpper, Álvaro к виду Propper, Alvaro?

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, utf-8, unicode

Возможно ли перевести слова со знаками над буквами перевести в те же слова, но без знаков? Есть два словаря вида:
`{name1:info1} и {name2:info2}`. name1 и name2 - одни и те же слова, но одно без знаков, другое со знаками(`{'Propper':info1} и {'Pröpper':info2}`)Нужно получить словарь `{'Propper':[info1, info2]}`, ну или `{'Pröpper':[info1, info2]}`(это наверное сложнее). Для этого мне нужно искать значения по ключу одного словаря в другом, но Python не считает эти слова равными.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import unicodedata

def strip_accents(s):
   return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
                  if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```

[отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/518232/1911548)

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить кроме кода какие-то свои комментарии, например, о функции unicodedata.normalize

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! Твоим способом не получилось, а вот так  - да!https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633310

Comment: Интересно, что эта функция также снесет шапку и у буквы й, например